# Why dashboard menu disabled in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I installed mysql workbench 6.1 on mac os x
When i connect to localhost all options are available!
But when i connect to the remote server, some of workbench options are disabled like dashboard menu in performance section.
How to enable this option?
[image]

Comment: What server do you use actually?

Answer (score 1):

Remote management is not set up for that connection. E.g. you have to set the path to your config file (which also determines the logs location) and you need to have the commands set to query the status of a server and to startup/shutdown it.

In order to adjust the settings for that click on the wrench button to open the connection settings and edit the values there to what you need. If this is a connection to a remote server you will have to change the "Remote Managment" settings too.

Answer (score 0):

Check

> mysql> show variables like '%perf%';
>   +---------------------------------------------------+---------+
>
> | Variable_name                                     | Value   |
>
> +---------------------------------------------------+---------+
>
> | performance_schema                                | OFF     |

Set it to `ON` in `my.cnf` and reboot. *et voilá !*

Comment: I turn on performance_schema but the dashboard menu not enable!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Performance Schema is available, it is disabled by default. To enable it, start the server with the performance_schema variable enabled. For example, use these lines in your my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema
```

Currently, only MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 are supported, because the performance_schema in MySQL 5.5 still lacked maturity.